# How is this word document encoded?

Tags: encoding, microsoft-word

We have a program that was written for us by a developer that we can no longer contact, the program opens word documents (forms) that we use in our company, you can tell they are Word documents as the 'Word' toolbar displays with this custom program and we can see the .doc files on the hard drive, the Save button is disabled in the program and when we open the .doc files in word the encoding is not standard as the forms are unreadable but look perfect in the custom program. If we can word out how he has done this we can hopefully convert the 100's of forms that we use.

One of the .doc files can be download below, I've scanned it for viruses, it's clean. If anyone can tell me how we can fix this I'd be very grateful.

http://www.2shared.com/document/Vb06LUmP/C4-002_Amenity_Fund_Constituti.html?

Many thanks
Steven

Comment: i added document to google docs and it says its not word document. so that custom program maybe corrupting header of the the file and makes it impossible to be opened by word.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at the raw file and all I can say its it's not a Word file.  The unix `file` command just sees it as `data`, and looking at the actual content there's nothing there that has any meaning to me whatsoever.

My guess is that the file is either encrypted in some way and the custom program decrypts it before sending it on to Word, or the file is a proto-form which just contains the instructions on how to make the form, and the custom program uses those instructions to craft the form and send it on to Word.

Without knowing either the encryption algorythm and key, or how the custom program uses this file to craft a form, there's not a lot a third party can do.